# How to pass optional macro args to a function

Tags: clojure

Clojure macro noob here.  I have a function with some optional parameters, e.g.

```
(defn mk-foo [name & opt]
  (vec (list* name opt)))
```

giving this:

```
user> (mk-foo "bar" 1 2 3)
["bar" 1 2 3]
```

I'm trying to write a macro which takes the same optional arguments and passes them transparently to an invocation of `mk-foo`.  So far I have this:

```
(defmacro deffoo [name & opt]
  `(def ~name ~(apply mk-foo (str name) opt)))
```

which has the desired effect:

```
user> (macroexpand '(deffoo bar 1 2 3))
(def bar ["bar" 1 2 3])
```

The use of `apply` to flatten the list `opt` feels clumsy.  Is there an idiomatic way to do this?  I'm guessing `~@` is needed, but I can't get the quoting right.  Many thanks.

Comment: I'm not particularly good with clojure, but it looks fine to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition about using apply served you well in this case. When you have a quoted form ` and then unqote all of them it can help to think about moving the un-quoting down to the smallest part or the list. This avoids using code to generate forms that could be simply written.

```
user=> (defmacro deffoo [name & opt] `(def ~name [~(str name) ~@opt]))       
#'user/deffoo
user=> (macroexpand '(deffoo "bar" 1 2 3))                            
(def "bar" ["bar" 1 2 3])
```

and here it is with the call to mk-foo:

```
(defmacro deffoo [name & opt] `(def ~name (mk-foo ~(str name) ~@opt)))     
#'user/deffoo
user=> (macroexpand '(deffoo "bar" 1 2 3))                                   
(def "bar" (user/mk-foo "bar" 1 2 3))
```

in this second case we move the `~` in one level and let the call to mk-foo stay quoted and only unquote the args required to build the parameter list (using splicing-unquote as you suspected)

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer.  Unfortunately, my real-life `mk-foo` is considerably more complex than the illustration posted.  It's not an option to expand it by hand inline. I must have the call.

Comment: revived the example using mk-foo from one of the previous edits.

Comment: This works, +1, but comes at the cost of defering the call to `mk-foo` to run time.